# Team Foundation Server 2017 Configuration Verification Certificate Error

Tags: ssl-certificate, team-foundation-server

Received the following error after running verification during TFS 2017 configuration.

Error:
VS403232: A trust chain for certificate '' used in binding '' cannot be verified. A certificate chain could not be built to a trusted root authority.

The certificate has been imported in Server Certificates on the Server.

How do I resolve this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to use the server certificate.